# image style plot issue with latest gnuplot 5.0.3

Tags: gnuplot

Recently I upgrade gnuplot to 5.0.3 and find that image style plot generate strange output with none square data. This does not happen in previous version (5.0.2). here is the minimal example

```
set term png
set output "a.png"
plot "-" using 1:2:3 with image title ""
#data
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 1

2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 3

3 1 8
3 2 6
3 3 4

4 1 8
4 2 6
4 3 4
```

the output image is [a.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgGtl.png)

When dealing with square data like this

```
set term png
set output "b.png"
plot "-" using 1:2:3 with image title ""
#data
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 1

2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 3

3 1 8
3 2 6
3 3 4
```

everything is fine [b.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nltsu.png)

is this a bug?

Comment: This is a known bug https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1767/

Comment: @Christoph Oh, thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem of sorting.

Try to sort by 2nd column like this:

```
1 1 2
2 1 1
3 1 8
4 1 8


1 2 3
2 2 2
3 2 6
4 2 6

1 3 1
2 3 3
3 3 4
4 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. At the moment, I switch the x and y axes. I use "u 2:1:3 w image" instead of using "u 1:2:3 w image"